# NLTK: Is there a term for this procedure?

Tags: nltk

I was reading some stuff about NLTK and I read something of a procedure that turns the word such as "you're" into two tokens "you" and "are". I can't remember the source. Is there a term for this or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip install contractions

```
# import library
import contractions
# contracted text
text = '''I'll be there within 5 min. Shouldn't you be there too?
          I'd love to see u there my dear. It's awesome to meet new friends.
          We've been waiting for this day for so long.'''
 
# creating an empty list
expanded_words = []   
for word in text.split():
  # using contractions.fix to expand the shortened words
  expanded_words.append(contractions.fix(word))  
   
expanded_text = ' '.join(expanded_words)
print('Original text: ' + text)
print('Expanded_text: ' + expanded_text)
```

[the source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-expand-contractions-in-text-processing/)